# Not able to update student data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to update the student data but I'm not able to update it.
In this code, a user needs to login in order to update his/her data and the user's username is the unique id that should match with the student's registrationNumber in order to login.

The error is showing "duplicatekey: registrationNumber" but I'm not updating/modifying the registrationNumber.

```
router.get('/edit', isLoggedIn, async(req, res) => {

    const registrationNumber = req.user.username
    const student = await 
    Student.findOne({registrationNumber})
    res.render('students/edit', { student })
})


router.put('/edit', isLoggedIn, async(req, res) => {

try {
    const registrationNumber = req.user.username
    const student = await 
    Student.findOneAndUpdate(registrationNumber, {...req.body})
        res.redirect('/students/profile')
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the username in the parameters, try to get the id, because it seems like it is expecting an id.

```js
router.put('/edit', isLoggedIn, async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const registrationNumber = req.params.edit
        const student = await Student.findOneAndUpdate(registrationNumber, {...req.body})
        res.redirect('/students/profile')
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`findOneAndUpdate` first param is an object ( like `find` or `findOne` ) so you have to provide an object instead a string

```
try {
    const registrationNumber = req.user.username
    const student = await Student.findOneAndUpdate({ registrationNumber }, {...req.body})
    res.redirect('/students/profile')
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

Let check the body (console.log(body)) to make sure body.name or registrationNumber doesn't exists in databse